# How to force remove software

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers

I have installed software for my TP-LINK Archer T2U (A USB Wireless Dongle) for  version 1.3.1 of the TP LINK wireless utility

The software came with the CD, but the TP LINK website has drivers.

Sadly, I've now found out the software supplied does not support Windows 10. Whilst I am on Windows 10, the software appeared to install without issue.

The device didn't work, I returned it. The software is not uninstalling.

If I go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features or direct to add or remove program, I can see the utility in question. I try to remove it, and it goes through the uninstall process.

At the end, it confirms it's removed. I still see it. I refresh the screen. It's still there. I attempt again. And repeat :)

In this gif, I do pause and continue the video so you don't want to wait while the application 'uninstalls' etc

[image]

Now to complicate it a little more. I've now purchased a Archer T9UH from the same company. The hardware won't accept the driver. I suspect potentially due to this legacy software.

So, I need to remove the original software and all associated files...

Any ideas?

How do I remove this?

*Edit*

Have also tried in Safe Mode. No luck

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some software can't be uninstalled normally, try to uninstall the software in the **safe mode**.

First enable **msiserver** in **safe mode**. Run the following command in **CMD.exe** as administrator.

```
 REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal\MSIServer" /VE /T REG_SZ /F /D "Service"
```

Then reboot the machine and hit **F8** to boot in safe mode, then try to uninstall the software again.